# Update database with every fresh install/reinstall titanium

Tags: ios, sqlite, titanium, titanium-mobile

How do you update the database every time there is a fresh install/reinstall?

Looked in the docs, can't find anything - so what ends up happening, if I have changed my models, I will get a SQLlite error upon a fresh update.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use :

```
Titanium.App.version
```

It will give you app version(Store it), at the time of initialization of your app check the current version.If it does not matches the one you have stored, just delete and recreate the database.

check out the [Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App-property-version) here.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Dragon, that works fine for checking version number. Had a few problems with updating the db. But it's a good starting point.